# Inductive proof for $3x+5y=n$ for $n\geq8$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

The following problem is to be proven with induction:

> You want to buy some cats, but cats are only sold in batches of 3 or 5. Prove inductively that for any n ≥ 8, there is a way to purchase exactly n cats.

I got as far as $3x+5y=n\implies 3k+5q=n+1$.

Also I proved the base case for $n=8$ which is $x=1,y=1$

However, I don't understand how to prove the inductive step.

Comment: Hint: show its true for $8,9,10$ (base cases) then add multiples of $3$ to get all larger numbers (inductive step)

Comment: "I got as far as 3x+5y=n => 3k +5q=n+1" No you haven't. You haven't stated what k and q are so how on earth can yow conclude 3k +5q=n+1?  But hint: if $3 x+5y=n $ then what does 3 (x+1)+5 y  equal? What about 3 (x-2)+5 (y+3) equal to?

Comment: Hint for alternative approach.  Instead of trying to prove you can buy ONE more cat, try to prove you can buy THREE more cats.

Comment: Search up "coin induction proofs". This is the same example

Comment: @KSplitX It's known by many names. To locate literature search on the many aliases, e.g. postage stamp problem, Chicken McNugget problem, Sylvester/Frobenius problem, Diophantine problem of Frobenius, Frobenius conductor, money changing, coin changing, change making problems, h-basis and asymptotic bases in additive number theory, integer programming algorithms and Gomory cuts, knapsack problems and greedy algorithms, etc.

Comment: @mathnoob But the number of cats can't be *negative*

Comment: Ah Right i'm sorry.